# Flutter - TextInputAction icon not changing

Tags: dart, flutter

so in my TextFormField widgets, I have set the TextInputAction to TextInputAction.next, I have also defined the focusNodes and onFieldSubmitted callbacks.

**One of the Text fields:**

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  maxLength: 2,
  validator: (value)=> value.isEmpty ? "Birth Month" : null,
  onSaved: (value)=> _birthMonth = value,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  focusNode: _birthMonthFocus,
  onFieldSubmitted: (v) =>FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_birthYearFocus)
)
```

The code above works. However, the icons aren't changing. I have ran it on 3 different emulators now, and it's still the same thing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..

```
final FocusNode _nameFocus = FocusNode();

final FocusNode _id = FocusNode();


 void _fieldFocusChange(
  BuildContext context, FocusNode nameFocus, FocusNode passwordFocus) {
nameFocus.unfocus();
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordFocus);
}
```

// below code define text field.

```
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  focusNode: _id,
   onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
                _fieldFocusChange(context, _id, _nameFocus);
              },
```